# How to position clabel text

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, contour

How would I go about keeping the contour label text along the outside the contour? Note - I don't want it inline with the contour. MCVE below.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Data=np.zeros((100,100))
Data[10:30,10:30] = 1
Data[60:80,60:80] = 1

f,ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

CS = ax1.contour(np.arange(0,100),np.arange(0,100),Data,[0,1])
ax1.clabel(CS, inline=False, fmt='%1.1f', fontsize=10)

plt.show()
```

Having checked the API I can't see anything (other than inline, manual click or specify the locations). So in the following image, I would like the labels slightly lower on the outside of the countour. [image]

Answer (score 2):

You may set the vertical alignment of the labels **after** creating them to align with their top to the initial position.

```
clabels = ax.clabel( ... )
for label in clabels:
    label.set_va("top")
```

This solution is semiautomatic. Because you do not a priori know on which side the label will be placed, you do not know whether to use `"top"` or `"bottom"` here. Also, for curved lines, this will not help at all and you would need to manually specify location (`ax1.clabel(CS, ..., manual=list_of_locations)`)

Complete example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Data=np.zeros((100,100))
Data[10:30,10:30] = 1
Data[60:80,60:80] = 1

f,ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

CS = ax1.contour(np.arange(0,100),np.arange(0,100),Data,[0,1])
cl = ax1.clabel(CS, inline=False, fmt='%1.1f', fontsize=10)
for l in cl:
    l.set_va("top")
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

A bit of a hack, which might also work with rotated labels (although I haven't tested it) could be to introduce a linebreak in front of the label. This would effectively also shift the label to the bottom.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import numpy as np

Data=np.zeros((100,100))
Data[10:30,10:30] = 1
Data[60:80,60:80] = 1

f,ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

CS = ax1.contour(np.arange(0,100),np.arange(0,100),Data,[0,1])
fmt = matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter("\n{x:1.1f}")
cl = ax1.clabel(CS, inline=False, fmt=fmt, fontsize=10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the response. My actual data has curved contours - I am surprised there isn't more support for clabel text in Matplotlib.

Comment: I have added another hacky solution to the answer, which might give better results in some cases.